# Ion-popover functionality and behaviour, centred instead of inline

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Can someone check the following stackblitz and explain to me the difference between the two buttons and why the ion-popover behaviour is different on each of them ?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8ckwz-oqix8v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton.component.html)

What I’m interested is why is the popover shown under the element on the “Click me” and why it’s shown as a popup ( centre of screen) on the exclamation button click ?

I was expecting the buttons to have the same behaviour since they are using the same function which is presentPopover, but instead whey it's using the emitClick for some reason the popover renders differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is subtle, not obvious: it's about target of the event. If in `presentPopover` method you log the `e.target` and click on 'Click me' button, you'll see that the target is the same `ion-button` you clicked, so the popover will be displayed at that position. However, when you click on icon (exclamation mark) with the same console log line, you'll see an error - because you are emitting without any content. Thus, the target is undefined and the popover will use window as reference point for the popup (no target, right?). Then again, if you write `this.emitClick.emit(event);` i.e. if you send the event to the emitter, your `presentPopover` will receive the element that's triggering the popover (which is icon button) and the popover will pop up alongside the icon. In short, if there's a defined target, popover will pop there, if not - it'll be centered.

Comment: Thanks, this actually was the way to go